# Display Angular4 Response Data From httpClient Iteration ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have this code from Angular 4

[image: enter image description here.]

And I have this (Array objects)response in console

[image: enter image description here.]

And I want to use this data in `*ngFor` to iterate this objects, how can I get this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you used `{observe: 'reaponse'}` for `HttpClient.get`, there will be full response(both header and body) back, you can use `*ngFor` to iterator `data.body` by exposing it as an **public variable** as below:

```
data: any;

this.http.get(..., {observe: 'response'})
    .subscribe(data => this.data = data.body);
```

Template code sample:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
  {{item.address}}
</div>
```

---

**`HttpClient.get` will return body of response by default without `{observe: 'response'}`**. You can also achieve it without `{observe: 'response'}` as below:

```
data: any;

this.http.get(...)   // without observe: response
    .subscribe(data => this.data = data);
```

Template code sample:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
  {{item.address}}
</div>
```

---

Also you can use a `async` pipe to subscribe and unsubscribe from `template` without expose data with an public variable:

```
data$: any;

this.data$ = this.http.get(...)
// or 
this.data$ = this.http.get(..., {observe: 'reaponse'}).map(data => data.body);
```

Template code sample:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data$ | async">
  {{item.address}}
</div>
```